# Spring Cloud Function with Docker

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, spring-cloud-function

I'm trying to build a Docker image to run on AWS Lambda but when I try to run it locally I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot
locate launcher:
/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/experimental/spring
boot-thin-launcher/1.0.28.RELEASE/spring-boot-thin-launcher
1.0.28.RELEASE-exec.jar
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    
    ...
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>        
        <!-- Dependencies -->
        <!-- spring-boot-starter-web -->
        <!-- spring-cloud-function-web -->
        <!-- spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws -->
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.28.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <shadedClassifierName>aws</shadedClassifierName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ./target/scf17-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-aws.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

What am I missing? Should I use the -aws.jar here?

Also, what do you prefer? Docker image or JAR file?

Running it as spring boot application works fine as well as uploading the `-aws.jar` file

The problem is when I try to run the image locally.

Thanks.

Comment: I think that AWS App Runner is a better option to run that container instead of Lambda. https://aws.amazon.com/apprunner/